What's the approach of rigging a character that has changing arms like megaman?
I have this character here where his arm changes to various weapons.

I'd want to figure out how to go about rigging this, where:

I can hide the actual arm, and change it to either of the weapons.
The weapons "follow" or utilize the same arm bone.

Any references to the techniques to achieve this would be greatly helpful!

Select the weapon, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select the forearm bone, press Ctrl P (Parent to) > Bone. Do it for the other weapons. To switch from a weapon to another you can keyframe the render visibility in the Outliner or in the Object panel > Visibility, the only drawback is that it stays visible in the Viewport but you can change its appearance

@moonboots with his normal arm being part of his body mesh, how do I hide that portion only? Is there a way to make an alpha mask that I "toggle" so the arm disappears?

You can use the Mask modifier to hide a vertex group

You could use Mask modifiers: Join the arms to the rest of the body, assign them to the same vertex group as the forearm vertex group, also assign them to their own vertex group (arm1, arm2, etc):

Give your body as many Mask modifiers as you have arms, each time choose the vertex group that you want to hide, press the invert button of the modifier, keyframe the modifier visibility when you want the object to be invisible:

Another solution:
Select the weapon, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select the forearm bone, press CtrlP (Parent to) > Bone. Do it for the other weapons. To switch from a weapon to another you can keyframe the render visibility in the Outliner or in the Object panel > Visibility, the only drawback is that it stays visible in the Viewport but you can change its appearance

Thank you for the detailed explanation! :)
